# Who do I award the bounty to?

Tags: discussion, bounties

This is my first post on META and although it is specific to a question I have asked, I feel it is generic in many ways.

I posted [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36610941/1256219), which remained unanswered for a time and so I offered a bounty.

I may be stating the obvious, but on StackExchange, when users ask a question, I believe that the response they hope for can be ordered as follows:

1. *A Solution* - Which includes the reason for the problem and a correct way to resolve it.
2. *A workaround* - No definitive reason is given for the problem, but a way to avoid it is provided.
3. *A reason* - No way to resolve the problem is provided, but the reason for the problem occurring is established.

In this specific instance, I rate **#2** higher than **#3** on the basis that the problem was causing production crashes and any workaround would be better than being enlightening as to why it was happening, and nothing else.

That said, on another question, **#3** would naturally rate higher than **#2**, if the reason for posting was purely for the insight of another's knowledge for educational purposes.

I digress:

The [first answer posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36672552/1256219) provided a workaround to prevent the issue.

A [latter post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36814155/1256219), provided reasoning as to why, but no solution (other than referencing the first post).

Additionally, I believe the latter post gained conclusion due to the first post and could perhaps not have drawn it otherwise.

So, finally, my question: **Who do I award the bounty to?**

Whilst the first answer solved my necessity for posting, the second may be of more use to those who read the question in the future. Is there a general consensus of the importance of **#1**, **#2** or **#3** on StackOverflow?

Comment: It is totally your call. You could accept one answer and bounty another if you feel they are both helpful but that is about it.

Comment: @rene Thank you, I didn't know you could do that. It would certainly be a great compromise. I shall do that.

Comment: If I had no idea which one to award the bounty to, I would award it to the one who put the most effort into writing their answer (the latter post) and accept the first answer so that future viewers can see a solution/workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no importance between the time in which the answers were posted. The importance here is the ***quality*** of the answers posted.

The bounty should be given to the answer you think helped you the most, kind of like your accept (but not as prestigious). If an answer given has solved ***your question*** consider giving it the ***accept*** as accepted answers are those the OP's believed were the best answers to their question. If you do accept the answer and would like to reward the other answer, give that answer the bounty. Or in most cases I've seen, give the accept and bounty to the same answer.

Like rene said:

> It is totally your call. You could accept one answer and bounty another if you feel they are both helpful but that is about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to note, time of the posts was never an issue, just the two different positives they provided.